# Change legend linetype color

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend

I have created a line graph using the qplot function in R with the following script:

```
qplot(fuclin, fitHYPT2, data=ib, geom=c("smooth"), method="glm", 
      color=ATgroups, linetype=BL_HYPT) +
    theme_classic() + 
    xlab("Time (years)") + ylab("MMSE") + 
    scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(24, 30)) +
    scale_color_manual(values=c("#CC6666", "#9999CC", "#66CC99", "#3399CC")) +
    scale_linetype(guide_legend(title = "Hypertension"))
```

It creates the following graph:

[image: graph]

I would like to change the color of the lines in the linetype legend to black (for some reason R made them blue, which makes no sense). Does somebody know how to do this?

Comment: `+ guides(lty = guide_legend(override.aes = list(col = 'black'))`

Comment: Great! Thanks :)

Comment: Do you perhaps also know how to change the color of the confidence intervals? I tried it with the geom_ribbon command but it did not work...

Comment: Use something like `fill = I("red")` or `fill = ATgroups` inside `qplot`